# Date conversion problems in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I have a date field in the third column of imported data as a string. I am trying to convert it to a proper date field.

```
mydata[1,3]
[1] 04/01/1957
```

The field is initially typed as a factor. I try to convert it to a date with:

```
mydata$Date <- as.Date(mydata$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

However, this seems to convert incorrectly. The new output is:

```
mydata[1,3]
[1] "2019-04-01"
```

Comment: `as.Date(mydata$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a duplicate a few dozen times over. `anytime::anydate(mydata[1,3])` will do it for you by first converting to character.

Here is your example, made reproducible:

```
R> dfact <- factor(c("04/01/1957", "05/01/1957", "06/01/1957"))
R> mydata <- data.frame(a=dfact, b=dfact, c=dfact)
R> mydata[1,3]
[1] 04/01/1957
Levels: 04/01/1957 05/01/1957 06/01/1957
R> anytime::anydate(mydata[1,3])
[1] "1957-04-01"
R>
```

Note also that your format string is wrong: you have a four-digit year for which you need `%Y` instead of `%y%`.  And what you (as well as the other answers / comments) missed as well is that `as.character()` is *mandatory* here:

```
R> mydata[1,3]
[1] 04/01/1957
Levels: 04/01/1957 05/01/1957 06/01/1957
R> as.Date(mydata[1,3], "%m/%d/%Y")  # used to be wrong, now works
[1] "1957-04-01"
R> as.Date(as.character(mydata[1,3]), "%m/%d/%Y")  # better but more work
[1] "1957-04-01"
R> anytime::anydate(mydata[1,3])  # easiest
[1] "1957-04-01"
R>
```

*Edit:* I at first overlooked that R now seems to add the `as.character()` step which *used to be* mandatory. Small steps.  `anydate()` still helps by allowing us to skip the format string for a fairly large number of possible formats.

Comment: This works, thank you. For anyone else who needs it, you must also install dependencies `anytime` and `RApiDatetime`

Comment: The `as.character` was no longer needed in R 4.0+ because `stringsAsFactors` now defaults to FALSE and both `data.frame` and the `read.*` family of functions use it.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is that you use %y instead of %Y.
%y is a two-digit year and %Y a four digit year.

Check https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Comment: As well as forgetting to convert from `factor` !!

Comment: I stand corrected. R 4.0.* now seems to do it, but earlier versions required it.